# Can you pass an angular expression as the actual ng-click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am just asking this as I cant find it anywhere.

I have an angular object `column.addOnParams`

This object containes a child element of `rowClick`, so it would be `column.addOnParams.rowClick`

In this child element contains the word `myclickevent();`

Is it possible to pass this to a `ng-click`.

So it would be as follows.

```
<td ng-repeat="column in columns" class="" ng-click="column.addOnParams.rowClick"></td>
```

I have tried it in the way above, but nothing gets generated, it just shows it as it is, after page load.

I also tried the following,

```
<td ng-repeat="column in columns" class="" ng-click="{{column.addOnParams.rowClick}}"></td>
```

That throws a reference error in angular,

> Syntax Error: Token 'column.addOnParams.rowClick' is unexpected,
>   expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression
>   [{{column.addOnParams.rowClick}}] starting at
>   [column.addOnParams.rowClick}}].

Any advice from you guys?

Side note when using this for the class object it works.

```
<td ng-repeat="column in columns" class="{{column.addOnParams.cssClass}}"></td>
```

The above statement generates and works perfectly.

Thanks to @J-D comment, the plunker solution worked like a charm  [Working solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/aWIS1oHja11hGm4pycMC?p=preview)

Using the `this` keyword was what I needed.

Comment: Try this column.addOnParams[rowClick](). The `rowClick` should be a string without `()` , like `myclickevent`

Comment: `ng-click="column.addOnParams.rowClick()"` ...  gets bound directly to controller method

Comment: Both of this different case will solve your problem. http://plnkr.co/edit/aWIS1oHja11hGm4pycMC?p=preview  and http://jsfiddle.net/nkuDW/1/

Comment: Thanks @J-D your solution worked./

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$eval` to call `myclickevent()`.

Example given below:

In your controller

```
$scope.myclickevent = function(rowClick) {
   //your functionality here.
}
```

and suppose you have `myclickevent()` string in  `column.addOnParams.rowClick`

Then In your html template

```
<td ng-repeat="column in columns" class="" ng-click="$eval(column.addOnParams.rowClick)"></td>
```

Hope it would help you.

Comment: Tried your solution, but it does nothing at all, really hoped it would work, but no function gets called, and no error is thrown either. So I guess that $eval is not working in this case.

Comment: Please have a look on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/19266/
Here addTodo function is calling by callAddTodo.

Comment: Thanks @Praveen your solution also worked, but had to tinker with some of the variables I had.

Answer (score 3):

```
<td ng-repeat="column in columns" class="" ng-click="{{column.addOnParams.rowClick}}"></td>
```

Above code will not work. ng-click is used for calling function when user click on it. You can pass parameter to function.
So you updated code will look like:

```
<td ng-repeat="column in columns" class="" ng-click="myClickFunction(column.addOnParams.rowClick)></td>
```

And in your controller, myClickFunction bind to scope.

```
$scope.myClickFunction = function(rowClick) {
   //do whatever you want to do
}
```

Based on your code **remove `{{}}`** then it will work fine:

```
<td ng-repeat="column in columns" class="" ng-click="column.addOnParams.rowClick"></td>
```

Comment: Your solution is working, but this is not what I am after, I don't want a `myClickFuntion()`, the child element should specify what the functions name is, and that should be called. As the function could be different for each column created. @SarjanDesai

Comment: That's why based on your code, check last line of answer. Remove {{}} from ng-click and you get function name from `rowClick`